# Stream HD movies using chromium lags every 4 seconds

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, hdmi, chromium

I am new to the raspberry family and would like to stream Hd quality movies from the internet.

Raspberry pi 3

I have the default rasbian operating system installed on my raspberry.
I also purchased both mpeg2 and vc1 codecs.

Using Chromium I for example open or try to play(Stream) a movie from 123 movies or other movie streaming sites. When you play the movie it plays correctly in hd format but as soon as you make it full screen it lags.. for example every 4 seconds it seems to stop for a second and then it continues to play. The Quallity stays HD there is no pixelation.

My raspberry is connected to my tv using an hdmi cable.

What I did:

1. Tried increasing the gpu memory in the settings restarting the pi but that did not work.
2. installed other browsers like firefox but no luck.
3. Checked the internet speed 40 Mb ps.

It seems to be a problem something to do with the resolution of the tv?
But if its not full screen it works without a lag.

Any solutions or suggestions? What I should do or how the pi actually works regarding streaming using the browser.

Comment: I suggest using a media centre OS such as Kodi and installing a video add-on called Exodus. This is going to give you a much better experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it has something to do with the resolution. When I set the resolution of the raspberry lower it works smoothly without any lag.