# HD/4k streaming to 65" tv

Tags: hdmi, streaming-video, media

So as indicated in the title, I'd like to be able to be able to use my pi3 as a media center of sorts and at the very least, stream some HD/4k videos to my tv (65" 4K Samsung). As it stands, I am able to comfortably play up to 720p50 if I keep the frame size down to about a quarter of my tv (i.e., I maximize chromium browser but don't enter full-screen). If I put the video into full-screen, it's smooth but buffers every couple seconds... (the circular 'wait' icon keeps rearing its ugly head). It can also play 1080p50, but then it buffers even when the video size is left to the default youtube size.

Things I have tried:

- verified usage of proper hdmi cable
- <s>internet speed (though it's a low 5Mbps, despite my desktop being 10x that -     this is a separate issue and have even switched to a j5create jue130 gigabit     ethernet adapter - to no avail [however, I don't think this is the issue bc I can simply wait until the video is fully loaded and the buffering doesn't go away]</s> EDIT: this has been fixed. Netgear "QoS" option was not functioning properly and jamming up my bandwidth. Turned it "off" and getting max-allowable download speed of about 70 Mbps.
- tvservice -d edid.dat, which had the opposite affect and turned my 65" TV into an oversized, pixely nintendo.
- overclocking my rpi3, also adding heatsinks and a fan

and on and on...

So, is there anyone out there that can comfortably stream >=HD-quality video to a big-screen tv? I can't (without the buffering).

P.S., here is my current config.txt

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxtreadme
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=16

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
config_hdmi_boost=6

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
total_mem=1024
#gpu_mem=74

arm_freq=1300
gpu_freq=500
core_freq=500
sdram_freq=500
sdram_schmoo=0x02000020
over_voltage=4
sdram_over_voltage=2

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# NOOBS Auto-generated Settings:
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# disables rainbown graphic on startup
disable_splash=1

# disables dithering on the PWM audio algo
# try if experiences white noise on audio jack
disable_audio_dither=1

start_x=
```

gpu log

```
Relocatable heap version 4 found at 0x3b000000
total space allocated is 44M, with 44M relocatable, 0 legacy and 0 offline
0 legacy blocks of size 2359296

free list at 0x3d533b20
9.0M free memory in 7 free block(s)
largest free block is 8.9M bytes

0x3b000000: free 8.9M
[  68] 0x3b8e4ba0: used 2.0M (refcount 1 lock count 1, size  2097152, align  256, data 0x3b8e4c00, d3Rual) 'CABAC output'
[  55] 0x3bae4cc0: used 1.2M (refcount 1 lock count 1, size  1305600, align    4, data 0x3bae4ce0, d1Rual) 'H264 dm_storage'
[  67] 0x3bc23900: used 420K (refcount 1 lock count 1, size   430080, align   32, data 0x3bc23920, d0rual) 'resize tmp'
0x3bc8c940: free 100K
[  78] 0x3bca5740: used 268K (refcount 1 lock count 1, size   274560, align   32, data 0x3bca5760, d0Rual) 'Vdec3 Msgbuf'
[  82] 0x3bce8800: used  14K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    14000, align   64, data 0x3bce8840, d3rual) 'h264_top_context'
[  77] 0x3bcebf20: used 1.0M (refcount 1 lock count 0, size  1048576, align  256, data 0x3bcec000, d3Rual) 'Vdec3 CDB'
[  53] 0x3bdec040: used 3.1M (refcount 1 lock count 1, size  3287200, align 4096, data 0x3bded000, d1rual) 'video_decodeRIL:image pool'
[  32] 0x3c10f900: used 3.1M (refcount 1 lock count 0, size  3287200, align 4096, data 0x3c110000, d1rual) 'video_decodeRIL:image pool'
[  31] 0x3c4331c0: used 3.1M (refcount 1 lock count 0, size  3287200, align 4096, data 0x3c434000, d1rual) 'video_decodeRIL:image pool'
[  30] 0x3c756a80: used 3.1M (refcount 1 lock count 0, size  3287200, align 4096, data 0x3c757000, d1rual) 'video_decodeRIL:image pool'
[  54] 0x3ca7a340: used 3.1M (refcount 1 lock count 1, size  3287200, align 4096, data 0x3ca7b000, d1rual) 'video_decodeRIL:image pool'
[  17] 0x3cd9dc00: used 3.1M (refcount 1 lock count 0, size  3287200, align 4096, data 0x3cd9e000, d1rual) 'video_decodeRIL:image pool'
[  61] 0x3d0c14c0: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 19085, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d0c2000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  69] 0x3d0e04e0: used 124K (refcount 2 lock count 19084, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d0e1000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  71] 0x3d0ff500: used 124K (refcount 2 lock count 19084, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d100000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  73] 0x3d11e520: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 19085, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d11f000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  70] 0x3d13d540: used 124K (refcount 2 lock count 19066, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d13e000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  74] 0x3d15c560: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 19084, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d15d000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  83] 0x3d17b580: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 19083, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d17c000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  51] 0x3d19a5a0: used 124K (refcount 2 lock count 19085, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d19b000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  63] 0x3d1b95c0: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 19085, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d1ba000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  64] 0x3d1d85e0: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 19082, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d1d9000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  23] 0x3d1f7600: used 124K (refcount 2 lock count 19085, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d1f8000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  36] 0x3d216620: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 19087, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d217000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[   8] 0x3d235640: used 124K (refcount 2 lock count 19085, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d236000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[   7] 0x3d254660: used 124K (refcount 2 lock count 19087, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d255000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[   6] 0x3d273680: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 19086, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d274000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[   5] 0x3d2926a0: used 124K (refcount 2 lock count 19086, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d293000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  56] 0x3d2b16c0: used  64K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    65536, align   32, data 0x3d2b16e0, d1rual) 'ril mem ril.video_decod-1'
[  43] 0x3d2c1700: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 37575, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d2c2000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  42] 0x3d2e0720: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 37575, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d2e1000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  12] 0x3d2ff740: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 37577, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d300000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  13] 0x3d31e760: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 37576, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d31f000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  16] 0x3d33d780: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 37576, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d33e000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  29] 0x3d35c7a0: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 37575, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d35d000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  66] 0x3d37b7c0: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 37577, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d37c000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  40] 0x3d39a7e0: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 37576, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d39b000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  39] 0x3d3b9800: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 37576, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d3ba000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  38] 0x3d3d8820: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 37577, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d3d9000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  37] 0x3d3f7840: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 37574, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d3f8000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  28] 0x3d416860: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 37574, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d417000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  27] 0x3d435880: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 37576, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d436000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  26] 0x3d4548a0: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 37580, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d455000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  25] 0x3d4738c0: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 37576, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d474000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
[  24] 0x3d4928e0: used 124K (refcount 1 lock count 37577, size   122880, align 4096, data 0x3d493000, d1Rual) 'sm_host_alloc'
0x3d4b1900: free 6.5K
[  10] 0x3d4b3300: used 1.1K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size     1024, align    4, data 0x3d4b3320, d0rual) 'resample coeff table data'
[  14] 0x3d4b3740: used   96 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size       12, align    4, data 0x3d4b3760, d0rual) 'resample coeff table'
[  45] 0x3d4b37a0: used  416 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      340, align    4, data 0x3d4b37c0, d0rual) 'resample context'
0x3d4b3940: free 2.2K
[  79] 0x3d4b4200: used  544 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      256, align  256, data 0x3d4b4300, d3rual) 'H264 dummy data partition'
0x3d4b4420: free 24K
[  80] 0x3d4ba420: used 8.1K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size     8192, align   32, data 0x3d4ba440, d0rual) 'audio_server'
[  76] 0x3d4bc460: used  17K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    17424, align   32, data 0x3d4bc480, d0Rual) 'H264 PPS'
[  75] 0x3d4c08c0: used 2.3K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size     2240, align   32, data 0x3d4c08e0, d0Rual) 'H264 SPS'
[  65] 0x3d4c11c0: used  64K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    65536, align   32, data 0x3d4c11e0, d1rual) 'ril mem ril.video_decod-1'
[  81] 0x3d4d1200: used  64K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    65536, align   32, data 0x3d4d1220, d1rual) 'ril mem ril.video_decod-1'
[  22] 0x3d4e1240: used  64K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    65536, align   32, data 0x3d4e1260, d1rual) 'ril mem ril.video_decod-1'
[  60] 0x3d4f1280: used  64K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    65536, align   32, data 0x3d4f12a0, d1rual) 'ril mem ril.video_decod-1'
[  62] 0x3d5012c0: used  64K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    65536, align   32, data 0x3d5012e0, d1rual) 'ril mem ril.video_decod-1'
[  33] 0x3d511300: used  64K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    65536, align   32, data 0x3d511320, d1rual) 'ril mem ril.video_decod-1'
[  34] 0x3d521340: used  64K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    65536, align   32, data 0x3d521360, d1rual) 'ril mem ril.video_decod-1'
[  41] 0x3d531380: used  192 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      128, align   32, data 0x3d5313a0, d1rual) 'ril.resize:in:0(OPQV)'
[  59] 0x3d531440: used  192 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      128, align   32, data 0x3d531460, d1rual) 'ril.resize:in:0(OPQV)'
[   9] 0x3d531500: used  192 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      128, align   32, data 0x3d531520, d1rual) 'ril.resize:in:0(OPQV)'
[  58] 0x3d5315c0: used  192 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      128, align   32, data 0x3d5315e0, d1rual) 'ril.resize:in:0(OPQV)'
[  11] 0x3d531680: used  192 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      128, align   32, data 0x3d5316a0, d1rual) 'ril.resize:in:0(OPQV)'
[  15] 0x3d531740: used  192 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      128, align   32, data 0x3d531760, d1rual) 'ril.resize:in:0(OPQV)'
[  72] 0x3d531800: used  192 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      128, align   32, data 0x3d531820, d1rual) 'ril.resize:in:0(OPQV)'
[  21] 0x3d5318c0: used  192 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      128, align   32, data 0x3d5318e0, d1rual) 'ril.resize:in:0(OPQV)'
[  52] 0x3d531980: used  192 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      128, align   32, data 0x3d5319a0, d1rual) 'ril.resize:in:0(OPQV)'
[  35] 0x3d531a40: used  192 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      128, align   32, data 0x3d531a60, d1rual) 'ril.resize:in:0(OPQV)'
[  46] 0x3d531b00: used 8.1K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size     8192, align   32, data 0x3d531b20, d0rual) 'audio_server'
[  18] 0x3d533b40: used  832 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      740, align   32, data 0x3d533b60, d1rual) 'ril mem ril.resize-0'
[  19] 0x3d533e80: used  832 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      740, align   32, data 0x3d533ea0, d1rual) 'ril mem ril.resize-0'
[  20] 0x3d5341c0: used  832 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      740, align   32, data 0x3d5341e0, d1rual) 'ril mem ril.resize-0'
[  57] 0x3d534500: used  832 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      740, align   32, data 0x3d534520, d1rual) 'ril mem ril.resize-0'
[  50] 0x3d534840: used  832 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      740, align   32, data 0x3d534860, d1rual) 'ril mem ril.video_decod-0'
[  49] 0x3d534b80: used  832 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      740, align   32, data 0x3d534ba0, d1rual) 'ril mem ril.video_decod-0'
[  48] 0x3d534ec0: used  832 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      740, align   32, data 0x3d534ee0, d1rual) 'ril mem ril.video_decod-0'
[  47] 0x3d535200: used  832 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      740, align   32, data 0x3d535220, d1rual) 'ril mem ril.video_decod-0'
[   4] 0x3d535540: used  576 (refcount 1 lock count 0, size      512, align    4, data 0x3d535560, d0rual) 'ILCS VC buffer pool'
[   3] 0x3d535780: used 6.8M (refcount 1 lock count 8, size  7096320, align 4096, data 0x3d536000, d1rual) 'ARM FB'
[   2] 0x3dbfafa0: used  16K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    16384, align   32, data 0x3dbfafc0, d0ruAl) 'audioplus_tmp_buf'
[   1] 0x3dbfefe0: used 4.0K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size        0, align 4096, data 0x3dbff000, d1rual) 'camera fast alloc arena'
small allocs not requested
```

P.S.S. - possible duplication of [Stream HD movies using chromium lags every 4 seconds](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/64056/stream-hd-movies-using-chromium-lags-every-4-seconds)

Comment: Have you tried allocating more memory to the GPU?

Comment: Gpu_mem set to 64 already. (Possibly even 74 according to some posts I've found about setting total_mem=1024)

Comment: That's the default.  I asked, "Have you tried allocating **more**..."

Comment: How high would you recommend.

Comment: I don't know that it will make any difference but it is easy enough to try.  Go with 256 and if that does anything cut it in half and see if it is still enough.  If not, then...well you tried.

Comment: Had the interesting affect of starving ARM mem so they 720p took extra time to render, with the same end result ensuing.

Comment: You haven't said what you are actually playing back beyond the resolution and frame rate, although you mention youtube -- which I *think* is H.264, but if it is something else that doesn't have hardware decoding support from the GPU, then it will not be very good.

Comment: https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=f35+uhd+youtube&view=detail&mid=771B005809232DD49C84771B005809232DD49C84&FORM=VIRE&PC=APPL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, see my post [Stream HD movies using chromium lags every 4 seconds](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/64056/stream-hd-movies-using-chromium-lags-every-4-seconds)

Everything you did I tried and did not work, I also played around with the puggins in chromium but nothing worked. Next I bought codecs from the Pi store... but still no success. What I had do to or what is working for me is to set the raspbery resolution down. 
**Application Menu > Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration > System > Set Resolution**

I think it has to do with rendering the resolution to the big screen that's causing the issue maybe not enough cpu..

But When I turned the resolution down to 720 by something it works.

Try it and see.

Comment: This seems to work, but before I get excited, doesn't that mean no video can be rendered at higher than 720p? Maybe I'm being picky but when I play the video, it doesn't look quite as sharp as when i've left the rpi3 configuration -> resolution at 1080x60...

Comment: Jip I could not get it better than 720p streaming from the browser some of the research I did they suggested installing software that uses the raspbery's GPU to render, but could not get it working properly. I also tried allot of different browsers but no luck. It would look more sharper if you increase the resolution but like I said the best I got without it lagging was 720p witch is HD and for me it was sufficient. The solution above helped me to stop the 'every 4 sec lag' :)

Comment: Ya, its obv a memory issue. The fact that it can play for 4 seconds before pausing is hope enough for me to keep pursuing it. At a minimum, you made me realize I should've trusted the tvservice utility and reduced the resolution of my desktop when using the tv as a monitor. I accepted your answer anyway.